# How to create facebook event via API 2023

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

as I'm searching, this is favourite topic through the years (because FB is constantly changing API capabilities).

I was wondering if anyone tries the same as I - create an event for my page via FB Graph API. As I found it was possible in the early days (before 2015), then FB disables it and now it's sort of unknown.

I found first mention in documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/) but it's limited to "Facebook Event Partners" only. You can apply to become one, but due to COVID-19 they has stopped accepting new partners (it's stated in the form, wondering what this has to do with FB events) and this endpoint allows you only to read events apparently.

But then I found another API endpoint, it's called "Official Events" [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/official-events/getting-started) and there they say you should be able to create APP and with sufficient permissions you should be able to create an event. I've tried it and I get this error "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.". It's not permissions issue, I have them right.

So I'm stuck here. Pleas If anyone has some experience, share them with me.

PS: I tried to ask ChatGPT and it provided me with fake code and fake link to documentation. When I stated the documentation is not existing, he apologized and said you can not :D

Comment: How did you solve this? I am now writing a web scraper to read events which is very tedious, so if there is a better solution I'd love to know

Comment: Unfortunatelly didn't :( I said to my client that is not possible and he must create new events via FB page.

Comment: So it's just not possible to create events via an API anymore?

Comment: I’m afraid it is not. At least I did not find the way.